# Partial performance of ES6 syntax in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

In order to use export / import in a Node.JS, we need either Babel or another third-party library, since ES6 modules are not supported natively. But why then can we use async / await, spread, rest without Babel? After all, all above mentioned have appeared since the ES6 syntax

Comment: Yes you can. The things that you've listed are natively supported in ES6.

Comment: ES modules are supported natively now: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html . It took a while to support it simply because it was a complex thing to get right. Unlike the other features you mentioned, ES modules are kind of conflict with the existing module system, CommonJS. So a main question was how interoperability between CommonJS and ES modules should work.

Comment: @Terry: FWIW, async/await is part of ES2017, not ES6.